# trigger.io duplicate builders running simultaneously?

Tags: trigger.io

Not critical, but just wondering - when iterating thru builds it seems that sometimes more than one is running at the same time... here's a screen shot.

[image]
<sub>(source: [kimosabe.net](http://kimosabe.net/trigger-dup-runs.png))</sub>

Closing the toolkit and reopening it fixes it.  Just wondering why it happens.

Thanks.

Comment: Not observed this before! Would be good to have some steps to reproduce this.

Comment: Build to a connected Android phone... the usual, make a change, rebuild, make a change, rebuild... if I had a syntax error somewhere, I'd hit the [kill] button, then rebuild again.  My guess is that when I hit the [kill] button the signal might be getting ignored or something... then I end up with the dup processes...

To reproduce, try [build] [kill] [build] [kill] ... and once the dups start the only way to get rid of them is to exit trigger and reload.